# Suggestion to solve the equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Suggestion to solve the equation:
$$T(n)=2T(n-1)+\frac{1}{n}+1?$$

Comment: Are you sure this simplification is correct?

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha,
$$
T(n) = 2^n\log 2 - \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1/2)^{k+1}}{n+k+1}.
$$

Comment: [OEIS A068102](https://oeis.org/A068102) is $n!\, T(n)$ and does not suggest a closed form

Comment: All of your questions are closed. In order to avoid this, please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/272831) and try to avoid [problem statement questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201/272831). This means including more than just the problem in the post. Where did it come from? What are you struggling with? What have you done? Note that this is not a homework solving site, you are expected to bring a bit to the conversation yourself.

Answer (score 1):

$$T(n) = 2. T(n-1) + \dfrac{1}{n}$$

$$T(n) - 2. T(n-1) = \dfrac{1}{n}$$.

Divide both sides by $2^{n-1}$, we get,

$$\dfrac{T(n)}{2^{n-1}}-\dfrac{T(n-1)}{2^{n-2}} = \dfrac{1}{n.2^{n-1}}$$

Let $g(n) =\dfrac{T(n)}{2^{n-1}}$. Then, the above equation can be rewritten of the form,

$$g(n) - g(n-1) = \dfrac{1}{n.2^{n-1}}.$$ Summing this from $n=2$ to $n=k$, we get,

$$g(k) - g(1) = \sum_{n=2}^{k} \dfrac{1}{n.2^{n-1}}.$$ So,

$$g(k) = g(1) + \sum_{n=2}^{k} \dfrac{1}{n.2^{n-1}}. $$ $g(1)$ can be found using $T(1)$. Hence,you can obtain the equation for $T(k)$.

NOTE: $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n.2^{n-1}}$ converges.

Consider $\sum \dfrac{x^n}{n}$. Then, $$\dfrac{d(\sum\dfrac{x^n}{n})}{dx} = \sum_{n \geq 1}x^{n-1}.$$ We know $\sum x^n = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$. So, $\sum \dfrac{x^n}{n} = - log(1-x)$. In your case, just plug in $x=1/2$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please explain a bit more on the steps where you considered $∑x^n/n$ and onwards? Specifically:
a)why did you considered the summation $∑x^n/n$? 
b)what does differentiating the summation $∑x^n/n$ means?
c)how did you arrive $∑x^n/n = -log(1-x)$ from $∑x^n = 1/(1-x)$?

Comment: @Polycom My idea was to prove $\sum \frac{1}{n2^{n-1}}$ converges. In order to do that, I considered $\sum \frac{x^n}{n}$ (because when $x=1/2$, this becomes our desired series). In order to evaluate $\sum \frac{x^n}{n}$, I considered $\sum x^n$ since $\frac{d( \frac{x^n}{n})}{dx} = \sum_{n \geq 0} x^n$.

We know, $\sum x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ (for $|x|<1$). Hence,  $\sum \frac{x^n}{n}= \int \sum x^n = \int \frac{1}{1-x} = -log(1-x) $.

Once you plug in $x=1/2$, you have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^n} = log 2$

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather rewrite it as

$$T(n)=2^{n-1}+2^n\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k2^k}$$

where $j=n-k$. Now notice that we have

$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k2^k}\le\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{2^k}=\frac12$$

and hence

$$T(n)\le2^n\implies T(n)\in\mathcal O(2^n)$$

As far as closed form goes, you can rewrite this in terms of the [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html):

$$T(n)=2^n\ln(2)-\frac12\Phi\left(\frac12,1,n+1\right)$$